# Why Parallels 8 installer looking into my Chrome's Cookies?

Tags: cookies, virtualization, macos, chrome, spyware

While trying to install Parallels on OS X I looked into `Activity Monitor` to find where is the installed Parallels located (it was weird that it stays invisible in Application folder). And than I found this:

[image: strange file opened]

So **Parallels installer opened a Chrome's Cookies file.**

I googled for this but no information found.

It is **a "little bit" strange** to see one app is going **looking into my cookies while install.**
I repeated the installation process to see at which moment it opens the Cookies file. So it was right **after authorization** of the Installer with the user password.

Any Ideas? Spyware? Installer is downloaded from the official page.

Comment: I'd bet it's somehow related to the "Coherence" feature that allows seamless usage of Mac and PC apps without actually entering the virtual OS

Comment: don't think so. why only Chrome and not other applications and services, why not safari, not firefox? And once more - Chrome is **not a default browser** on my OS.

Comment: I don't think this is a security question. It is more a question for the parallels team, as they will have decided the behaviour..

Comment: why not? it is about "is it objectively normal behaviour or not", so is it dangerous or not?

Comment: As mentioned by other users, I would ask the Parallels team if I were you. There's not much we can tell you about a closed source program. If you could, please answer the question once you receive an appropriate answer from them.

Answer (score 2):

Parallels Desktop is a closed-source application, so the community isn't going to be able to help you out much here other than offering rumor and conjecture.

Your best bet is to contact Parallels to see if you can get *them* to explain themselves.

Comment: yep, but I just wanted at least to here smth. like "yep" sounds strange or "no, its normal so", before I can go further.

Comment: isn't it a "security/privacy" question?

Comment: @static - could be. Who knows. The data on your computer is there for any authorized program on your computer to read. There's no way around that. Whether or not it's a concern depends on what the program does with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Any time a program starts poking around in your cookies or browser configuration it is **a little bit strange** however only further investigation by either yourself or by requesting the information from Parallels will tell you for sure. If i were you i'd check to see *what* file was accessed (all cookies? Just one? Did it read or write? etc) and I'd also investigate if it transmitted them at all anywhere. Maybe its an activation process done via your browser or something unusual.

Its speculation on my part here but perhaps it imports some of your cookies into the guest browsers? There appears to be some linkage for browsing between OSX and Windows as [described here](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v6/docs/en/Parallels_Desktop_Users_Guide/27344.htm)

Hope that helps somewhat :)

Answer (score 1):

Those cookies are used to provide seamless user experience and integration between host, guest and web. Parallels Desktop stores its version in it.
For example, "Open in IE" browser button extension can use installed PD version to understand can it work or not. But mostly it must be used by Parallels web site not to show you promos about new PD version if you already have it installed.